# CSS селекторы к innerHTML

Tags: html, css, css3, dom, angular2

День добрый, нужна помощь.
Асинхронный запрос, приходит объект свойство которого текст в тегах.
Помещаю для отображения в темплейт.

```
<div class="some_class" [innerHTML]="something"></div>
```

Теперь нужно применить для него какие то стили в css файле.

```
.some_class {
display:inline-block
}
```

Не видит, все аналогичные классы на странице видят, то что помещено с помощью innerHTML не видит. Но нормально отрабатывает та разметка которая есть в нем.
Angular2 если это поможет конечно.

Comment: Нашел ответ, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html

Answer (score 2):

Это связано со спецификой работы `innerHtml` и инкапсуляцией `angular 2`

1 Способ

Подключить файл css через `<link rel="stylesheet" href="путь к файлу"></link>` и задать в нем нужные классы, которые имеются в innerHtml. То есть делаем как в любом проекте.

2 Способ

Задать стили с помощью `:host >>> .class`.

В примере ниже имеется некий блок `<div [innerHTML]="someHtml"></div>` в который будет вставляться некий HTML

```
 <p class="styleP1">Hello</p>
 <p class="styleP2">Hello</p>
```

с классами `.styleP1`, `.styleP2`.

К первому `<p class="styleP1">Hello</p>` стиль не применится, потому что он не задан через :host, второй же `<p class="styleP2">Hello</p>` окрасится в красный цвет.

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <div [innerHTML]="someHtml"></div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [
    `:host >>> .styleP2 { color: red; }
    .styleP1, .styleP2 { color: red; }`
  ],
 })
 export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.someHtml = `<p class="styleP1">Hello</p>
      <p class="styleP2">Hello</p>`;
  }
}
```